# Pysftp "cd" fails against AIX server with "OverflowError: mode out of range" error

Tags: python, sftp, aix, pysftp

Having trouble getting the `pysftp.connection.cd()` working – not sure what I am doing wrong or what the issue is.  I can achieve what I need by passing the full remote path into the relevant methods. But if try to change the remote active directory I get error.  Relevant code is below:

```
with ps.Connection('hostname or IP address', username='username', password='secret', cnopts=cnopts) as conn:
    print("Connection successful....")
    print(conn.listdir()) # this works
    print(conn.listdir(remote_location))  # this works
    with conn.cd(remote_location):  # this throws an error
        print(conn.listdir())
```

The error I get is below here:

```
File "C:\Users\username\.conda\envs\data_wrangling\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 508, in cd
    self.cwd(remotepath)
  File "C:\Users\username\.conda\envs\data_wrangling\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 524, in chdir
    self._sftp.chdir(remotepath)
  File "C:\Users\username\.conda\envs\data_wrangling\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 659, in chdir
    if not stat.S_ISDIR(self.stat(path).st_mode):
OverflowError: mode out of range

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\username\my_code\python\mears_to_er_interface\sftp_chdir_test.py", line 41, in <module>
    with conn.cd("remote_location"):
  File "C:\Users\username\.conda\envs\data_wrangling\lib\contextlib.py", line 112, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "C:\Users\username\.conda\envs\data_wrangling\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 511, in cd
    self.cwd(original_path)
  File "C:\Users\username\.conda\envs\data_wrangling\lib\site-packages\pysftp\__init__.py", line 524, in chdir
    self._sftp.chdir(remotepath)
  File "C:\Users\username\.conda\envs\data_wrangling\lib\site-packages\paramiko\sftp_client.py", line 659, in chdir
    if not stat.S_ISDIR(self.stat(path).st_mode):
OverflowError: mode out of range
```

---

The output for `conn.stat(remote_location).st_mode` is `83448`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paramiko uses Python `stat` module in the [`SFTPClient.chdir`](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/sftp.html#paramiko.sftp_client.SFTPClient.chdir) implementation to check if the path is a folder (and not a file).

The problem is that the Python `stat` module can work with 16-bit permissions only. Your SFTP server returns permissions with 17th bit set. That results in the `OverflowError`.
There's not much you can do about it. See this Python issue: [stat.S_ISXXX can raise OverflowError for remote file modes](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/83910).

Just avoid using the `SFTPClient.chdir`. Simply use absolute paths everywhere in the Paramiko API, instead of relying on paths relative to the working directory set using `chdir`.

The only other place where Paramiko currently uses the `stat` module is the `SFTPAttributes.__str__`. Otherwise you should be safe.

I've reported this to the Paramiko project: https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/issues/1802

---

If you want to analyze the permission bits in your own code, just mask out the excess bits. See:
["OverflowError: mode out of range" in Python when working with file mode/attributes returned by Paramiko](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74766393/850848)

Comment: Thank you Martin.  I will accept this as the answer because although it doesn't strictly fix the issue, as you pointed out there doesn't seem to be a fix at this point in time.  Appreciate your help looking into this.