# "OverflowError: mode out of range" in Python when working with file mode/attributes returned by Paramiko

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

I am trying to make a SFTP script to go through a directory and get all the files in it, inside this directory there are subdirectories that I would like to exclude. However when I use the `stat.S_ISREG` function it gives an error of

> OverflowError: mode out of range

From what I have read it seems like an error that Paramiko has with the handling of the bits that the server returns. Is there a way to solve this error, or some other way to differentiate files from folders based on the `st_mode`? I was thinking of validating if the `st_mode` is greater than `34000` exclude it and take it as a folder but I don't know if it is correct.

The code is the following:

```
client_ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
client_ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
client_ssh.connect(host,username=user,password=pwd)
sftp_client = client_ssh.open_sftp()
df_file_info_sftp = pd.DataFrame([attr.__dict__ for attr in sftp_client.listdir_attr(directorio_remoto)]).sort_values("st_mtime", ascending=False)
for row in df_file_info_sftp.itertuples():
    print (row.filename)
    if stat.S_ISDIR(row.st_mode):
        print('Carpeta:')
    if stat.S_ISREG(row.st_mode):
        print('Archivo:' + row.filename)
sftp_client.close
client_ssh.close
```

The error is:
[image]

From what I have read, it seems to be an error that Paramiko has with the handling of the bits returned by the server (apparently there are more than 16 and that is why the error)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no *error* in Paramiko. It's just that Paramiko (or actually your server) can return more permissons bits than Python `stat` module can handle.

I've explained this in:
[Pysftp "cd" fails against AIX server with "OverflowError: mode out of range" error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65832614/850848)

If you work with such server, you either have to analyze the bits without using the `stat` functions, like:

```
S_IFMT = 0o170000
(row.st_mode & S_IFMT) == stat.S_IFDIR
```

Or trim the excess bites, before passing the value to `stat` functions:

```
stat.S_ISDIR(row.st_mode & 0xFFFF)
```

---

*Obligatory warning: Do not use `AutoAddPolicy` this way – You are losing a protection against [MITM attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man-in-the-middle_attack) by doing so. For a correct solution, see [Paramiko "Unknown Server"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10670217/850848#43093883)*.

Comment: Thanks Martin, use the trimming form with 0xFFFF as you indicate and it works perfectly, if I had read the article you mentioned, but all I was missing was this indication of how to fix it, now I can classify files and folders easily